# regular expression is not working in c++

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to match a regular expression in c++ using *regexec*.

This is my pattern which i tried was working fine in java

```
(^.*([0-9]{6}).*([0-9]{9}).*([0-9]{6,7}).*([0-9]{2,3}).*)
```

I tried this, but getting wrong output

```
(.*)[[:digit:]{6}](.*)[[:digit:]]{9}(.*)[[:digit:]]{6,7}(.*)[[:digit:]]{2,3}(.*)
```

Following is my c++ code :

```
static int compile_regex (regex_t * r, const char * regex_text) {
    int status = regcomp (r, regex_text, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NEWLINE);
    if (status != 0) {
        char error_message[MAX_ERROR_MSG];
        regerror (status, r, error_message, MAX_ERROR_MSG);
        printf ("Regex error compiling '%s': %s\n",
                 regex_text, error_message);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
static int match_regex (regex_t * r, char * to_match) {
    char * p = to_match;
    int n_matches = 10;
    regmatch_t m[n_matches];
    int i = 0;
    int nomatch = regexec (r, p, n_matches, m, 0);
    return nomatch;
}
int match ( char * find_text ,string regex_txt) {

    char regex_text[regex_txt.size()+1];
    strcpy(regex_text , regex_txt.c_str());
    regex_t r;
    int ret ;
    compile_regex (& r, regex_text);
    ret = match_regex (& r, find_text);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Please provide one or more example of input strings that doesn't match with provided regex when it it is supposed to

Comment: the java regex syntax above is valid given the standard c++ regex library. why don't you use it?

Comment: I tried with this input "@000172@ 000002000[ 000001@ 13 8" but it also except this "@000456789172@ 000002000[ 000001@ 13 8"

Comment: I am passing -std=c++11 But given java regex is not working -UnNy

Comment: Now I test this pattern "[[:digit:]]{6}" for input "123456" which gives correct result but it also accept "1234567890"

Comment: this is C++? wow.. you *do* realise that you are using posix regex functionality rather than the new regex functionality in the standard library right?

Comment: The code above relies on `regex.h`, a POSIX library. In POSIX, `.` matches any char, in Java, it matches any char but line break chars. Replace `.` with `[^\r\n]`, and make sure `[[:digit:]{6}]` is fixed as `[[:digit:]]{6}`

Comment: As you can see above comment i have tried [[:digit:]{6}], but it matched more than 6 digit @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Update your question. Add the strings you test against, the rule for the pattern, expected behavior.

Comment: yes, i am using posix regex in our .cpp file, is there any wrong using it? @– Nim

Comment: Please update the question. Nothing wrong with the POSIX approach, but your question is unclear and impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with POSIX regex, however if you wanted to do this in portable c++11, something like the following will work..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    auto str = string("@000172@ 000002000[ 000001@ 13 8");
    auto rx = regex("(^.*([0-9]{6}).*([0-9]{9}).*([0-9]{6,7}).*([0-9]{2,3}).*)");
    auto it = sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), rx);
    auto ie = sregex_iterator();

    cout << "Found " << distance(it, ie) << " matches\n";
    // print submatches
    for (auto i = it; i != ie; ++i) {
        for(auto s : *i) {
            cout << s << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

And https://regex101.com/ confirms, that the code is doing the right thing - i.e. the output looks like this:

```
Found 1 matches
@000172@ 000002000[ 000001@ 13 8
@000172@ 000002000[ 000001@ 13 8
000172
000002000
000001
13
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using dot that matches also digits, use `\D` that matches NON digit:

```
(^\D*([0-9]{6})\D*([0-9]{9})\D*([0-9]{6,7})\D*([0-9]{2,3})\D*)
```

Comment: dot can match any character, but \D can  matched any character that is not a decimal digit so i can't replace it with dot

Comment: @NomanAkhtar: Why? Please, edit your question and add test cases. What strings must match and what must not? Your regex matches an infinite length of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your compiler is actually supports regex. I had the situation with GCC when it looks like regex are supported (all headers are exists, compilation is OK and so on), but actual result of matching is wrong. Updating GCC to the newer version solved the problem.

Comment: I have gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: @noman-akhtar check some basic code examples from here, for example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex